# Chemfig misaligned in subfigure environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats, chemfig

I don't know how to align the both following molecules, written with chemfig, correctly. Both structures are aligned with the `[t]` option following `\begin{subfigure}`. The second structure is misaligned to the top. It seems, like it uses the starting point of the both structures (in both cases the highest edge at the left border of the structures) for alignment.

Is there a possibility to define an invisible box around the structures or to solve this problem somehow differently?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{CH_3-[6]-[:-30]O-[6]*6(-=-(-[6]S(=[4]O)(=[0]O)-[6]N*6(---N(-[6]CH_3)---))=-(-[:30]*6(=N-(*5(-(-[::-54]-[::-60]-[::60]CH_3)=N-N(-[::-54]CH_3)--))=-(=[2]O)-HN-[,,2]))=)}
        \caption{structure 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{1}{
        \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{*6(=(-[6]O-[::60]-[6]CH_3)-(-[::-60](*6(-[,,1,2]HN-(=[6]O)-*5(-N(-[::-54]CH_3)-N=(-[::-54]-[::60]-[::-60]CH_3)--)=-N=)))=-=-)}}
        \caption{structure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{xyz
    \label{fig:xyz}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: misaligned structural formulas]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Both structures are aligned exactly as expected: the *first* atom in a `\chemfig{...}` formula determines the baseline. That is, the `CH_3` of the first and the edge of the 6-ring `*6(...)` of the second. And those *are* aligned. If you define the second structure in a different way, i.e., starting with the CH3 of the propyl then you'll get the alignment you want…

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too. Unfortunately, I need the structure either in the orientation given above or in this: [https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73464/is-rotation-flip-of-skeletal-structural-formula-of-sildenafil-claim-6-okay]

Comment: Good, if you found another solution. Nevertheless I didn't suggest to change the orientation of the molecule but the *implementation*…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, got it. I found a way here: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=23024

I solved the problem by giving tikz an individual baseline with

```
\chemfig[baseline=(mybase.north)][...]{...}
```

and a definition of the baseline at the CH3 in the upper right corner:

```
...[::-60]@{mybase}CH_3...
```

So the corrected code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{CH_3-[6]-[:-30]O-[6]*6(-=-(-[6]S(=[4]O)(=[0]O)-[6]N*6(---N(-[6]CH_3)---))=-(-[:30]*6(=N-(*5(-(-[::-54]-[::-60]-[::60]CH_3)=N-N(-[::-54]CH_3)--))=-(=[2]O)-HN-[,,2]))=)}
        \caption{structure 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{1}{
        \chemfig[baseline=(mybase.north)][scale=0.6]{*6(=(-[6]O-[::60]-[6]CH_3)-(-[::-60](*6(-[,,1,2]HN-(=[6]O)-*5(-N(-[::-54]CH_3)-N=(-[::-54]-[::60]-[::-60]@{mybase}CH_3)--)=-N=)))=-=-)}}
        \caption{structure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{xyz
    \label{fig:xyz}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And it results in:

[image: vertical well aligned two subfigures of structural formulas]